# Ubuntu 14.04 64bit Cannot install Gimp

Tags: 14.04, package-management, gimp

I am at the end with my knowledge. I cannot install Gimp of unmet Dependencies. I tried quite a lot but nothing. It is a fresh install on a Dell Latitude E6420. I added the ppa to the software center but it gives the error: Package dependencies cannot be resolved.
Any idea?
thx
Eric

Comment: What PPA did you add???

Comment: Also post outputs of these commands,  `sudo apt-get install gimp` , `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`  and `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Comment: please accept my answer if it solved your problem,comment if you got any error =)

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have to add any PPA to the softwarecenter to install GIMP, because it should be present in the default software sources. As you are on Ubuntu 14.04 you might have added an experimental PPA, which needs some new packages. Delete the PPA, update and search for GIMP. Click on install.

Comment: After removing kesselgulasch ppa I getE: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: could solve with sudo rm /var/..lists, sudo apt-get update, software center -Gimp - There isn’t a software package called “gimp” in your current software sources.

Comment: same result when try to install in terminal

Comment: Strange - although deleted from ppa: still there claws-mail-ppa-trusty.list
claws-mail-ppa-trusty.list.save
google-chrome.list
google-chrome.list.save
matthaeus123-mrw-gimp-svn-trusty.list
matthaeus123-mrw-gimp-svn-trusty.list.save
otto-kesselgulasch-gimp-trusty.list
otto-kesselgulasch-gimp-trusty.list.save
xorg-edgers-ppa-trusty.list
xorg-edgers-ppa-trusty.list.save

Comment: kesselgulasch and matheus still there

Comment: @user269162 we cant help you if you dont provide us with information. Please  check your comments and post outputs of of commands accordingly.

Comment: user269162, "Unable to lock directory" means there is another installation process running. For example, while you are logged into Synaptic Package Manager you cant install from Terminal or Softwarecenter. Close everything and try again.

Comment: so now the additional ppa: are not anymore there, so software center uses only the ones that are there from when installed ubuntu. when I now install gimp from software center it says: There isn’t a software package called “gimp” in your current software sources.

Comment: You are sure that everything you have removed was "additional"? (and before being to quick with a "yes" here: how do you verify that?)

Comment: Look at the output: I do something wrong because ls shows: claws-mail-ppa-trusty.list
claws-mail-ppa-trusty.list.save
google-chrome.list
google-chrome.list.save
matthaeus123-mrw-gimp-svn-trusty.list
matthaeus123-mrw-gimp-svn-trusty.list.save
otto-kesselgulasch-gimp-trusty.list
otto-kesselgulasch-gimp-trusty.list.save
ubuntuhandbook1-ppa-trusty.list
ubuntuhandbook1-ppa-trusty.list.save
xorg-edgers-ppa-trusty.list
xorg-edgers-ppa-trusty.list.save          that kesselgulasch and matheus are still there, but in software center  and synaptics they are not listed anymore, so it seems removing does

Comment: not really remove but why?

Comment: Gimp not available in software center. When installing in Terminal, it says The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libbabl-0.1-0 (>= 0.1.10) but it is not installable
        Depends: libgegl-0.2-0 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not installable
        Depends: libmng2 (>= 1.0.10) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
When I try to install above mentioned libs, it installs but still when trying to install gimp, gives me the same errors. Getting headache, no wonder ubuntu cannot beat windows

Comment: maybe the problem is 64 bit version, maybe nvida graphic driver?

Comment: Problem solved: In the resource window change from main server to USserver - ftp.usf.edu and then install via synaptics

Comment: Well, good luck with your system - I guess you'll need it :/

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal  by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run,

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Or open **Software Centre** and install.

If you want from PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then run,

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

If you want to delete your earlier PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove {ppa:whatever/preview}
```

If you want to delete a PPA repository as well as all **packages installed/upgraded from the PPA**, you can use ppa-purge command.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge 
sudo ppa-purge {ppa:whatever/preview }
```

here {ppa:whatever/preview} relace with your previous PPA.